# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns wrong cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView that uses custom cells, loaded from nibs, and hooked up to a controller (using initWithNibName:bundle:).  Basically, I've noticed that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns a cell that has already been loaded, but when it shouldn't.

Here are my delegate methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tv cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
  return [[self controllerForTableView: tv cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath] cell];
}

- (TableViewCellBaseController *) controllerForTableView: (UITableView *) tv cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
  [self checkValidTableView: tv];

  UIViewController *controller;
  Class class;
  Event *event;
  int row = [indexPath row];

  DLOG(@"at index path row: %i", row);

  if (row == [currentEvents count]) {
    controller = [self tableCellContainerFromNibName: nibName
                                           tableView: tv
                                             atIndex: row
                                           withClass: class];
  } else {
    class = [EventFeaturedTableViewCell class]; // TODO: OR class = [EventNonFeaturedTableViewCell class];
    event = [self findEventFromIndex: row];

    lastSelectedEvent = event;
    DLOG(@"event: %@", event);

    controller = [self tableCellContainerFromNibName: NSStringFromClass(class)
                                           tableView: tv
                                             atIndex: row
                                           withClass: class
                                             perform: @selector(initTableCellWithController:)
                                                  on: self];
  }

  return controller;
}

- (TableViewCellBaseController *) tableCellContainerFromNibName: (NSString *) nibName
                                                      tableView: (UITableView *) tableView
                                                        atIndex: (int) index
                                                      withClass: (Class) class
                                                        perform: (SEL) selector
                                                             on: obj {

  CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: nibName];
  TableViewCellBaseController *controller;

  DLOG(@"Cell: %@", cell);
  DLOG(@"Cell Identifier: %@", nibName);

  if (cell == nil) {
    controller = [[class alloc] initWithNibName: nibName bundle: nil];

    if (obj) {
      [obj performSelector: selector withObject: controller];
    }

    // run this after setting data as controller.view eager loads the view
    cell = controller.cell = controller.view;
    cell.controller = controller;
  } else {
    controller = cell.controller;

    if (obj) {
      [obj performSelector: selector withObject: controller];
    }
  }

  return controller;
}

- (void) initTableCellWithController: (EventsIndexTableViewCell *) controller {
  controller.event = lastSelectedEvent;
}
```

The Custom Cells have been hooked up in IB to the controller using the controller's view property as well as a 'cell' property.  The Custom Cells have a unique identifier set directly in the nib.

I've already verified that the data in the controller is correct.

Here's the effect I'm seeing in the simulator:

http://screencast.com/t/NI2Tpc7GKEi

Notice that the event 'Atlantic Bay' shows up first in the table, then later on in the table.  When scrolling back up, it no longer shows up as the first entry in the table!

Comment: But controller's setEvent: method has been overridden in order to modify the cell content or not? because if the answer is not, you're essentially changing the dequeued cell structure (cell.controller) but not the content.  Consider that the cell structure is created once when the controller Nib is loaded and its view created and if you don't update it explicitly using controller's setEvent: I don't see other places in the code where you do it. The first cells in the table are fine because  the Nibs are called each time, and this happens until the system start reusing queued cell.

Comment: Hey viggio24 - see the comments under Rob's post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue viggio24's line, I agree that I don't see a place that you're properly reconfiguring the cell. When you -dequeue... you're going to get a cell that already has "stuff" in it. It's your job to reset everything visible.

You should also read carefully [Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18). Typically you use `-loadNibNamed:owner:options:` for this, rather than `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Comment: How would I reconfigure the cell?  On first load the cell gets loaded along with the content in the containing controller's viewDidAppear.  Is there something similar to viewWillAppear for the cell?  viewWillAppear: doesn't seem to work on the controller.

Comment: The equivalent of -viewWillAppear for cells is `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: So I'd want to call [cell setNeedsDisplay] in -tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: You should not need to call `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` at all. Certainly not here, since the system is already getting ready to display it. You just need to finalize your configuration of the cell you're handed.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks a ton Rob. Turns out I was still expecting viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear to end up being called when the cell was redisplayed.  Here was the diff which finally made a difference:  https://gist.github.com/0efef5e32849a119784f